# Is it possible to make repo searchable, but not visible to the public?

Tags: github, visibility

Github newbie here.

If my understanding is correct, there are only 2 visibility modes for a repository: "Public" and "Private". However, neither of these modes satisfy my needs. What I need is something in between.

I would like to make a repo *searchable*, meaning when a user visits my profile, they see that a repo exists, and also *private*, meaning they don't actually see the code when visiting my profile (but they can request permission to view it).

Such a feature/functionality would be really nifty as I don't want just anybody to have access to my code, but would like to be able to share it with potential employers.

Is it possible to do such a thing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!
KC

Answer (score 0):

Not really you can take the andvantages of Premium with private repos.